# Does the ApplicationInsights.config need to sit in the output directory's root directory

Tags: azure-application-insights

Does the ApplicationInsights.config need to sit in the output directory's (bin folder) root directory, or can i put it inside sub folders in the output directory (bin folder)

```
<Content Include="Service References\**" Exclude="Service References\Application Insights\ApplicationInsights.config" />
<Content Include="Service References\Application Insights\ApplicationInsights.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

[image]

I can't find information on whether that's allowed or not:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, this is currently the case; It only looks in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` for `ApplicationInsights.config`

It's [hard-coded](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Extensibility/Implementation/Platform/PlatformImplementation.cs#L45-L48) for the dotnet framework implementation at least.

Interestingly, the netstandard version [returns null](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Extensibility/Implementation/Platform/PlatformImplementation.cs#L152-L154) for that method.

Answer (score 2):

My colleague in ops has deployed the solution and apparently the ApplicationInsights.config is not picked up unless it's included in the root directory. Hopefully Microsoft will add that to their documentation... Or perhaps allow it to be configured in the future.

Seems odd that it just has to be in the root of the bin folder. *shrugs*